How to extract APIM verification ID needed for managed custom domain using Azure CLI?
In other Azure CLI scripts for web apps and containers, I'm able to extract the verification ID needed for creating managed custom domains with a command like this:
# Set Variable for Verification ID of the Container App
$ContainerAppVerificationID = Invoke-Expression "az containerapp show --name $ContainerApp --resource-group $ResourceGroup --query 'properties.customDomainVerificationId' --output tsv"


However, this same concept is not working for APIM resources. I've tried this below, but it does not work.
# Set Variable for Verification ID of APIM
$APIM_VERIFICATION_ID = Invoke-Expression "az apim show --name $APIM_NAME --resource-group $APIM_RESOURCE_GROUP --query 'properties.customDomainVerificationId' --output tsv"


Does anyone know how this variable can be set dynamically in CLI?
I have tried other commands that have worked on web apps and containers, the same results were not received.
Thank you

There is no customDomainVerificationId property existed for an Azure APIM instance. Can you check and confirm which ID you want to retrieve. @jobatthemall

Hi Jahnavi, yes I see that as well. When outputting all properties to a JSON I'm unable to see what I'm looking for. But it's when you go to add a managed custom domain, it requires a TXT record to be created and it gives a value. In web apps and containers the value is called customDomainVerificationId, but I guess that's not the case for APIM. I will put a screenshot in the main body of the question, please let me know if you have any other information. Thank you!

@Jahnavi, actually it will not let me add a photo, but it looks like this:
To prove domain name ownership and grant access to the certificate add following DNS records to your domain configuration.
TXT record for 'apimuid.'
String of text here
CNAME record for ''
default domain here for apim
